# Unsuccessful attempt to send email from gmail.com

Tags: php, smtp, pear

I have file with name contact.php, inside I have form:

```
<form method="post" name="kontakt" action="send_mail.php">
  <fieldset class="formularz_kontaktowy">
    <legend>Formularz kontaktowy</legend>
    <div><label id="lblStatus"></label></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="txtName" title="Imię i nazwisko" id="txtName" class="text"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="txtEmail" title="Email" id="txtEmail" class="text"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="txtTitle" title="Tytuł" id="txtTitle" class="text"></div>
    <div><textarea cols="30" rows="10" name="txtMessage" id="txtMessage" class="text" title="Treść wiadomości"></textarea></div>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSendmail" value=Send">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

send_mail.php

```
<?php
  require_once "Mail.php";

    $from = "<mailaddress@gmail.com>";
    $to = "<mail2@gmail.com>";
    $subject = "Hi!";
    $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

    $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $port = "465";
    $username = "<mailaddress@gmail.com>";
    $password = "password";

    $headers = array ('From' => $from,
      'To' => $to,
      'Subject' => $subject);
    $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
      array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

    if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
      echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
     } else {
      echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
     }

?>
```

after click `btnSendmail` in browser I have URL, for example: `localhost/contact.php?txtName=Mary+Smith&txtEmail=mailMail%40gmail.com&txtTitle=dfd&txtMessage=fgdf&btnSendmail=Send`, but mail doesn'y sent and I have not message. Why?

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. Please do a `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the very beginning of your script. Additionally you should [enable error logging](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-howto-turn-on-error-log-file.html) and follow the error log.

Comment: The url in the browser is not the result of `POST`ing a form to `send_mail.php`. Have you posted your original code?

Comment: Yes, it's my original code, I changed only login/password to mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. I had two tags , one in template and second, nested in contact.php. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
$username = "<mailaddress@gmail.com>";
```

to

```
$username = "mailaddress@gmail.com";
```